# How i make a Notification alarm sound?

Tags: android, audio

How i create a simple notification alarm sound with my alarm.mp3 file?My file is inside /res/raw directory.What code i need?

```
   notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" +  context.getPackageName()             "/"     + R.raw.alarm );
```

Answer (score 2):

put mp3 file in raw folder inside res. and use below code.

```
 notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+context.getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.your_sound_file_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use simply following code

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.mySound );
```